Force nested loop over observables to wait for all
I've read about forkJoin, async, await, and also tried out angular life cycle methods, but finally found no good solution.
I need to wait until initiAttributesMap has finished his job before next code lines run.
If I use a setTimeout
I get the map fully filled.
But I want to avoid setTimeout.
Thank you.
somewhereInCode (){
    initAttributesMap();        
    setTimeout(() => {
        //do Other things                
            }, 20);
}

public initAttributesMap(bObjects: BObjects[], attributesMap: Map<string, string>){
    bObjects.forEach( (bObject: BObjects) => {
        if ( bObject.cValues !== null ) {
            bObject.cValues.forEach( ( cValue: CValue ) => {
                this.myService.getValueTypes( cValue.source).subscribe(
                        ( possibleValues: PossibleValues[] ) => {                                
                            let displayName = possibleValues.find( foundValue => cValue.id == foundValue.id ).displayName;
                            attributesMap.set( cValue.attributeName, displayName );
                        } );
            });
        }
   });

}

If you want wait while all attributes will be initialized:
somewhereInCode (){
  initAttributesMap().subscribe(() => {
    //do Other things
  });        
}

public initAttributesMap(bObjects: BObjects[], attributesMap: Map<string, string>){
  const resObs: Observable<unknown[]> = []
  bObjects.forEach( (bObject: BObjects) => {
    if (bObject.cValues !== null) {
      bObject.cValues.forEach( ( cValue: CValue ) => {
        const obs = this.myService.getValueTypes( cValue.source).pipe(
          tap(( possibleValues: PossibleValues[] ) => {
            let displayName = possibleValues.find( foundValue => cValue.id == foundValue.id ).displayName;
            attributesMap.set( cValue.attributeName, displayName );
          })
        )
        resObs.push(obs);
      });
    }
  });
  return forkJoin(...resObs);
}


Thank you. I first tried this solution and made a mistake: I forgot to subscribe! After I tried the solution of @prince09 I faced that my problem was still there namely code run to next lines without waiting for the attributesmap to get filled out!  Again I looked at your solution and noticed my mistake!

If I understood your requirement clearly then here's how you can do this,
import { forkJoin, of } from 'rxjs';
import { flatMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Assume you have a service called AttributeService to fetch attribute details

function initAttributesMap() {
  // Assuming componentA, componentB, and componentC are arrays of objects
  componentA.forEach(a => {
    // Process each component B
    a.componentBs.forEach(b => {
      // Process each component C, if available
      if (b.componentCs) {
        forkJoin(
          b.componentCs.map(c => {
            // Process each attribute of component C
            return forkJoin(
              c.attributes.map(attributeId => {
                // Fetch attribute details using a service
                return AttributeService.getAttributeDetails(attributeId).pipe(
                  map(attributeDetails => ({
                    attributeId: attributeId,
                    attributeDetails: attributeDetails
                  }))
                );
              })
            );
          })
        ).pipe(
          flatMap(attributesOfCs => attributesOfCs)
        ).subscribe(
          // Process each attribute details
          attributesOfC => {
            // attributesOfC is an array containing the attribute details of a component C
            attributesOfC.forEach(attribute => {
              // Process each attribute detail here
              const componentBId = b.id;
              const componentCId = /* get component C id */;
              const attributeId = attribute.attributeId;
              const attributeDetails = attribute.attributeDetails;
              
              // Store or process the attribute details as needed
            });
          }
        );
      }
    });
  });
}


We loop through each component A, then each component B, and then each component C (if available).
For each component C, we use forkJoin to wait for all attribute details to be fetched before proceeding.
We then use flatMap to flatten the array of arrays of attribute details into a single observable stream.
Finally, we subscribe to the flattened observable stream to process each attribute detail.


Thank you. Sorry that I have changed my description. But got your answer and I will try it right now and let know.

you can use forkJoin, firstValueFrom and map from rxjs.
  async somewhereInCode() {
    await firstValueFrom(initAttributesMap());
     //do Other things      
  }

  public initAttributesMap(bObjects: BObjects[], attributesMap: Map<string, string>) {
    const forkJoinArray = [];
    bObjects.forEach((bObject: BObjects) => {
      if (bObject.cValues !== null) {
        bObject.cValues.forEach((cValue: CValue) => {
          forkJoinArray.push(
            this.myService.getValueTypes(cValue.source).pipe(map((possibleValues: PossibleValues[]) => {
              let displayName = possibleValues.find(foundValue => cValue.id == foundValue.id).displayName;
              attributesMap.set(cValue.attributeName, displayName);
            }))
          )
        });
      }
    });
    return forkJoin(...forkJoinArray)
  }

